# Not able to read file name with space Batch Commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

**I have batch script which reads the first line of a csv file**

```
set textfile="input test.csv"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
)
```

It is taking "input test.csv" as a string and not reading the file
If i remove the quotes in text file it is showing  **The system cannot find the file input.**

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you are executing this in the same directory as `"input test.csv"` file?

Comment: @npocmaka yes i am sure

Comment: Try to debug it a bit, add `dir "input test.csv"` just in front of your `set /p` and perhaps even the `DIR` command can't find the file. Btw. perhaps you need to show more code, as some syntax sugar can cause/solve trouble. Do you use the line you showed as is, or did you use something like `set /p line= < %myFile%`?

Comment: I was wrong the error was not in that line...i have a for loop where IN (%textfile%) is used....textfile=input test.csv. But if i make it "input test.csv" it is taking as a string

Comment: It's descibed in the help of `FOR /?`. `FOR /F %%V in (Files)` but `FOR /F %%V in ("String")`. Try a look at the `usebackq` option